# arrays, removeFirst() not working?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a method that should remove the first element of an array, however when I run my code, the debugger flips out and I'm not sure why.

This is my removeFirst() method:

```
Loan & ListOfLoans ::  removeFirst(){
    index = 0;
    //determine if the container needs to be shrunk
    if((numberOfElements < capacity/4) && (capacity >= 4)){ // shrink container when     array is 1/4 full
        cout<<"shrinking array! \n";
        Loan ** temp = elements;
        elements = new Loan * [numberOfElements/2];
        //copy temp array to elements
        for(int i = 0; i<numberOfElements; i++){
            temp[i] = elements[i];
            numberOfElements = numberOfElements/2;
            delete [] temp;
        }
    }
    numberOfElements--;
    return **elements;
}
```

And my header file for good measure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "loan.h"

using namespace std;

class ListOfLoans {

public:
ListOfLoans(int initial_size=4);

~ListOfLoans(void);


 void add(Loan & aLoan);
 Loan & first() ;
 Loan & removeFirst();
   // answer the first element from the list and remove it from the list
    // if the resulting list is more than three quarters empty release some memory
 Loan & removeLast(); 
   // answer the last element from the list and remove it from the list
    // if the resulting list is more than three quarters empty release some memory
 Loan & next();
 int size(); 

private: 
Loan ** elements; //actuall stuff in the array m_pnData;
int numberOfElements; //number of elements in the list  stize of the array? m_nLength
int capacity; //size of the available array memory 
int index; //used to help with the iteration
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with this code. Here is an annotated copy.

```
// Return by reference cannot be used if you are removing the element.
// This looks like a Java-ism.
Loan & ListOfLoans ::  removeFirst(){
    // unused variable
    index = 0;

    if((numberOfElements < capacity/4) && (capacity >= 4)){
        cout<<"shrinking array! \n";
        Loan ** temp = elements;
        // you are allocating an array of size numberOfElements/2...
        elements = new Loan * [numberOfElements/2];

        // then accessing elements which are way past its end.
        for(int i = 0; i<numberOfElements; i++){
            temp[i] = elements[i];
            // you are halving the array size in every iteration
            numberOfElements = numberOfElements/2;
            // you are deleting temp in every iteration,
            // causing double-frees
            delete [] temp;
        }
    }
    // if the array does not need to be shrunk,
    // you are actually removing the last element.
    // the removed element is not freed and is leaking.
    numberOfElements--;
    // you are returning the first element,
    // which is not removed.
    return **elements;
}
```

I would strongly recommend to replace `ListOfLoans` with an STL container, such as `std::deque`. If you can't do this, here is a minimal fixed version.

```
Loan ListOfLoans::removeFirst() {
    Loan to_return;
    if (numberOfElements == 0) {
        return to_return; // return default value, there is nothing to remove
    }
    if ((numberOfElements < capacity/4) && (capacity >= 4)) {
        Loan **old = elements;
        capacity = capacity / 2;
        elements = new Loan*[capacity];
        for (int i=0; i < numberOfElements - 1; ++i) {
            elements[i] = old[i+1];
        }
        to_return = *old[0];
        delete old[0];
        delete[] old;
    } else {
        to_return = *elements[0];
        delete elements[0];
        for (int i=0; i < numberOfElements - 1; ++i) {
            elements[i] = elements[i+1];
        }
    }
    --numberOfElements;
    return to_return;
}
```

Comment: I'm really new to c++ so please be patient with me... I am unable to use the declaration of Loan to_return because there is no appropriate default constructor... I think my constructor requires that I initiate each new loan with 5 parameters, and I am not able to have two constructors as I have been given the header file and cannot change it

Comment: In that case investigate `boost::ptr_deque` or `boost::ptr_list`. Those are wrappers for standard containers which allow them to work with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

**Try moving `delete [] temp;` under the for loop.**

It looks like one issue may be that `delete [] temp;` is being called repeatedly within the for loop.
The first iteration through the loop, the memory associated with `temp` will freed.  Subsequent iterations through the loop will access the freed memory.

There may be other issues.  It would be very helpful to see the output from the debugger.

Comment: Good call on the delete.  Unfortunately that isn't the issue.  I don't really understand what is going on with the debugger (I've never used one) but I am running the code in Microsoft Visual Studio and a iosfwd file keeps popping up.